# Get the element from a json

Tags: python, json, parsing, constructor

I'm new in python and i'm trying to implement a little bellman-ford algorithm. I got some rate from different currency in a json which look like that:

```
{"USD_JPY": "88.1911719", "USD_USD": "1.0000000", "JPY_EUR": "0.0086441", "BTC_USD": "122.5311820", "JPY_BTC": "0.0000923", "USD_EUR": "0.6695743", "EUR_USD": "1.2624079", "EUR_JPY": "129.3438373", "JPY_USD": "0.0111120", "BTC_BTC": "1.0000000", "EUR_BTC": "0.0110526", "BTC_JPY": "12543.0532689", "JPY_JPY": "1.0000000", "BTC_EUR": "90.3821109", "EUR_EUR": "1.0000000", "USD_BTC": "0.0071458"}
```

I tried to get instantiate my object that way but it seem to not working properly, and even if it would have work I think it's not really efficient (If the order of the currency change I'm screw)

```
def __init__ (self, rates):    
    res = json.load(rates)
    self.EURToEUR = 1.000000
    self.USDToUSD = 1.000000
    self.JPYToJPY = 1.000000
    self.BTCToBTC = 1.000000
    self.EURToUSD = json[6]['EUR_USD']
    self.EURToJPY = json[7]['EUR_JPY']
    self.EURToBTC = json[10]['EUR_BTC']
    self.USDToEUR = json[5]['USD_EUR']
    self.USDToBTC = json[15]['USD_BTC']
    self.USDToJPY = json[0]['USD_JPY']
    self.BTCToEUR = json[13]['BTC_EUR']
    self.BTCToJPY = json[11]['BTC_JPY']
    self.BTCToUSD = json[3]['BTC_USD']
    self.JPYToEUR = json[2]['JPY_EUR']
    self.JPYToUSD = json[8]['JPY_USD']
    self.JPYToBTC = json[4]['JPY_BTC']
```

If you guys could tell me how it's works and an efficient way to read my JSON I will be glad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to access the json object using indices. The key is all you need. Also, you want to access `res`, which is your object you loaded, not `json`, the name of the module

`self.EURToUSD = res['EUR_USD']`

insead of this:

`self.EURToUSD = json[6]['EUR_USD']`

Comment: I get the following error: self.EURToUSD = json['EUR_USD']
TypeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Comment: Oh try using `self.EURToUSD = res['EUR_USD']`

Answer (score 1):

How about using [collection.namedtuple](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple)?

```
from collections import namedtuple

data = {"USD_JPY": "88.1911719", "USD_USD": "1.0000000", "JPY_EUR": "0.0086441", "BTC_USD": "122.5311820", "JPY_BTC": "0.0000923", "USD_EUR": "0.6695743", "EUR_USD": "1.2624079", "EUR_JPY": "129.3438373", "JPY_USD": "0.0111120", "BTC_BTC": "1.0000000", "EUR_BTC": "0.0110526", "BTC_JPY": "12543.0532689", "JPY_JPY": "1.0000000", "BTC_EUR": "90.3821109", "EUR_EUR": "1.0000000", "USD_BTC": "0.0071458"}
Currency = namedtuple('Currency', data.keys())
currency = Currency(**data)
```

then you get your data like this:

```
>>> currency.USD_JPY
'88.1911719'
>>>> currency.USD_USD
'1.0000000'
```

So, in you example, it will be:

```
def __init__ (self, data):       
    Currency = namedtuple('Currency', data.keys())
    self.currency = Currency(**data)
```